# Using urllib2.urlopen() to load a URL without waiting for a response

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

I just want to send the request but don't want to waste time waiting for the responses. Because the responses are useless to me.
I looked up the python doc but I didn't find a solution.
Thanks for any advice.
I have tried to use
`urllib2.urlopen(url, timeout=0.02)`
But I can't sure if the request is actually sent out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called asynchronous loading, and here's a [blog post explaining how to do it with urllib2](http://pythonquirks.blogspot.co.uk/2009/12/asynchronous-http-request.html). Sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import urllib2
import threading

class MyHandler(urllib2.HTTPHandler):
    def http_response(self, req, response):
        print "url: %s" % (response.geturl(),)
        print "info: %s" % (response.info(),)
        for l in response:
            print l
        return response

o = urllib2.build_opener(MyHandler())
t = threading.Thread(target=o.open, args=('http://www.google.com/',))
t.start()
print "I'm asynchronous!"
```

This will load the URL without waiting for a response.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve asynchronous function calling like that is by using the callable in its own thread or subprocess.

http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Thread
http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process

It appears that there are HTTP libraries for Python that already implement such functionality, however, such as [`grequests`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests) or [`requests-futures`](https://github.com/ross/requests-futures) (both of which are based on the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library, an improvement over `urllib2` in terms of API).